# Is it possible to find out if FT index is updated?

Tags: full-text-search, xpages

I need to find out if a FT index is updated or not on a Domino database. if it is not updated I want to display how many documents are not indexed, possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do use the database method `search(String formula, DateTime dt, int max)` to search for documents created or modified after the last index time stamp and then count the number of documents found:

```java
DocumentCollection unindexedColl = db.search("Form=\"specificform\"", db.getLastFTIndexed(), 0);
unindexedCount = unindexedColl.getCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code snippet:

```
If(db.lastmodified > db.lastftindexed) Then
    ' Database was modified after index updated , it may be a document or design
    Dim T As New NotesDateTime(db.lastftindexed)
    Dim UnindexedCount As Long
    ' Find the modified document after index updated
    UnindexedCount = db.Search({@All}, T, 0).Count
Else
    ' FT index is up to date
    UnindexedCount = 0
End If
MsgBox UnindexedCount
```